# Issues Changing Position for Facebook Messenger Chatbot on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, position, facebook-messenger

I am currently using `Wordpress` for my website. And I just install the **Insert Header Footer Block** plugin. [Picture of the extension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5cUC.png)

However, I need to move the bot to the left and bring it up a bit as not to block another element on my page. I am told that I need to key in the CSS, however I am not sure what element to change the the CSS code to.

Here is the Link to the site: [Site](https://iamgifted.com.my/)

Here is what I have.

```
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
          <div id="fb-root"></div>
          <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
                xfbml            : true,
                version          : 'v7.0'
              });
            };
    
            (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    
          <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
          <div class="fb-customerchat"
            attribution=install_email
            page_id="1558679400867992" theme_color="#e8632e">
          </div>
```

When i place the  code in the div class="fb-customerchat"

```
<style>
.fb-customerchat
{ 
   position:absolute;
   bottom: 30px;
   left: 16px;
 } 
  </style>
```

The chat widget disappears completely .

Comment: Can you please send a link to it so we can debug?

Comment: Noted. I have edit the post with the link. Thanks

Comment: The facebook button that you're trying to push to the left is the one that is current in orange, correct? In the right bottom corner

Comment: Yes the one in arange to the right  now. I want to push it to the left above the other chat button

Comment: Hey there @DiegoFortes just wondering if you were able to to debug the question. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to align the bubble to the left:

```
iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_in_v2,
iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2  {
    left: 10px !important;
}

.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_advanced {
    left: calc(10px * 2) !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: where did you place the code? Do I need to add a <style> the code </style>. Cuz when i put it within the style  and in the fb-customerchat container it dissapears again

Comment: `'<!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
      <div class="fb-customerchat"
        attribution=install_email
        page_id="1558679400867992"
  theme_color="#e8632e">
<style>
iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_in_v2,
iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2  {
    left: 10px;
}

.fb_dialog.fb_dialog_advanced {
    left: calc(10px * 2);
}
</style>
      </div>`

Comment: Well, this is CSS code. You need to put it in a CSS file or within `<style>` tags in `html` file.

Comment: I have updated the code to use `!important`, try that. Your code in the comment is correct.

Comment: Nope. still doesnt appear

Comment: I have tested it in the browser as I've shown in the screenshot. The code is working properly. This new issue you're bringing up is naturally beyond the scope of the question